# Using TaskFactory() vs TaskFactory(CancellationToken)

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

When using a TaskFactory (default constructor) and you want your tasks cancelable then you do the typical:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token), token);
// or the equivilant
var factory = new TaskFactory();
factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token), token);
```

According to MSDN if instead of `TaskFactory()` you use `TaskFactory(CancellationToken)` then:

> The CancellationToken that will be assigned to tasks created by this
>   TaskFactory unless another CancellationToken is explicitly specified
>   while calling the factory methods.

This leads me to believe that I can do this:

```
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(token);
factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token)); // don't need to pass token to StartNew()
... // imagine a few more tasks created just like above
// now create a special task that marches to its own drummer (token)
factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(differentToken), differentToken);
```

Of course why would I do that? It would seem to make more sense to just use the Task.Factory.StartNew() for the one-off task (unless I had other common config I guess). But I digress. So that's what I *thought*, except I see a number of examples online that essentially look like this:

```
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(token);
factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token), token);
```

Passing the same exact token to StartNew() as the factory is allegedly configured to automatically associate with the tasks created by this factory. So I'm not sure if I'm just seeing examples that are doing work they don't need to do, or if there is something fundamental I'm misunderstanding here. After all, if I'm going to explicitly pass the token to StartNew(), then what is the point of passing it to the TaskFactory constructor?

Comment: Why would you even use `Task.StartNew` if there is `Task.Run` ? Why would you use a `TaskFactory` when there is a `CancellationTokenSource`?

Comment: @Sievajet `StartNew` has lots of options that `Run` doesn't.  `Run` just covers the most common cases.  For example, you need to use `StartNew` if you want to use a non-default task factory.  `TaskFactory` and a CTS just do very different things; I'm not sure why you think they're equivalent to begin with.

Comment: @Servy You're right. Didnt know why there was a `TaskFactory`. I do now :). I checked the source on https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs,840bfb852d901722,references. There are overloads where without the `CancellationToken`. In these cases the one from the constructor will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs,840bfb852d901722,references) for the `TaskFactory`:

Constructor:

```
public TaskFactory(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler)
{
    CheckMultiTaskContinuationOptions(continuationOptions);
    CheckCreationOptions(creationOptions);

    m_defaultCancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    m_defaultScheduler = scheduler;
    m_defaultCreationOptions = creationOptions;
    m_defaultContinuationOptions = continuationOptions;
}
```

Here is an overload without the `CancellationToken` parameter and how it's implemented:

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] // Methods containing StackCrawlMark local var have to be marked non-inlineable            
    public Task<TResult> StartNew<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
    {
        StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
        Task currTask = Task.InternalCurrent;
        return Task<TResult>.StartNew(currTask, function, m_defaultCancellationToken,
            m_defaultCreationOptions, InternalTaskOptions.None, GetDefaultScheduler(currTask), ref stackMark);
    }
```

As you can see `m_defaultCancellationToken` from the constructor is used when you're not using the one with the `CancellationToken` parameter.

So passing the `CancellationToken` in the constructor is only usefull if you use the `TaskFactory.StartNew` without the `CancellationToken` overloads

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure and didn't want to overlook some nuance that I could have been missing. Therefore I must be seeing some crazy examples that are passing the cancel token (redundantly) to their taskFactory.StartNew() call even though they constructed their taskFactory with the same token.